# Are my websites hacked?

Tags: php, wordpress

Suddenly all kind of Wordpress sites show very strange code in the header.php and index.php files. It is across several servers so looks like someone really got ahold of all my server details.

The code inserted in the header looks like this:

[image]

What can this be? And any tips on how to get rid of this problem (I am talking about like 50 sites here..)

I tried decoding the code in all kinds of decoders but nothing got it decoded..

Comment: Yes, you've been hacked. You should also check your installations for files like "paypal.php" or similar - hackers may be using your site for phishing attacks.

Comment: Your code has been edited and you don't know why? Yes, you've been hacked.

Comment: Take a look on http://www.unphp.net/ . This should be able to tell you what code it is.

Comment: That`s bad.. unphp.net cannot decode this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does sound like a hack. I don't think you are the first as there is a thread at wordpress.org about this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/headerphp-hacked-need-advice-have-tried-everything

Answer (score 1):

There is a very strong probability that you are hacked. But the interesting part should be to check how they got into the system. First thing that comes to my mind seeing all the code is the use of nulled themes and plugins. Often times one might install plugins from unknown sources, there is a reasonable amount of propability that these plugins might have been altered by some user. So you might have not been hacked by a live hacker, which would have been annoying.

Try copying the red part (string) and decoding it with php's base64_decode function, 90% of the hackers use base64_decode and eval function to obfuscate their code. Mostly this obfuscated code is used to add a form field where they can then upload a file which is directly executed.

The only solution is to change the passwords, find the code thats responsible and remove it from all over your site (try multiple file search and replace). Install a good firewall, i like wordfence. If possible use a 2nd degree of verification, something like an sms or google account. Dont install nulled themes and plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Decoding the code gives nothing, anywhere. Tried like 10 tools. I will look into wordfence!

Comment: Well thats interesting, Can you share the complete code in your header?

Comment: Hi, I got it decoded now! It was decoded in 5 layers of base_64 and completely obfuscated. Got it decoded by running my own (recursive) base 64 decoding script, now I must found out what the code is doing

Comment: Here is the decoded and formatted PHP file, can you make anything out of it? http://www.filedropper.com/formathackcode

Comment: PS: it seems to be the same code as in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647441/what-does-this-malicious-php-code-found-in-a-wordpress-install-do, can you maybe explain what harm the code is, I don`t really understand the answer there

Comment: Well i just quickly looked at the code. There are 2 parts to it, the first part is pretty generic, i.e it goes through all the files and check if any directory is writable and if it is then copies a notorious file to it. This is usually used as a backdoor for future attacks. The second part is a bit more complex, its getting the ip addresses of all your visitors and then doing something on it. The rest of the code is in ml.php, so we cant know for sure what the ip address are used for. It might be infecting all your users and storing their ip addresses for future ddos attacks (zombies).

Comment: BY the way the information is being sent to scriptutrecht.nl so its surely a nulled plugin.

Comment: well scripttutrecht.nl seems to be an innocent site, but the fact that you and the scripttutrech.nl are from neitherlands raises my suspicion. The real hacker will be somewhere in the dark but he used this website as a front. Finding how he got in is really important, i have a very strong feeling that you are using a local hosting provider or a provider which is hosting all nl websites on his server. So if the hacker successfully hacks one of the website on that server, technically he will be able to get access to all the websites on that server.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. Strange thing seems to be that it is hacked accross 2 server, one VPS in AMS, Netherlands and the other I don`t know (shared host). But I got no clue on how they got in..

Comment: Seems like it is all cleared out now. Cleaned the hacky code on all sites, changed all passwd, and hasn`t come back since. Maybe we already removed the source a while ago. Any further suggestions on how to make things more secure / avoid this next time?

Comment: Well it might not be an option for you now,  but if its a new website try using a different db prefix secondly never user the username "admin" that comes default with it. If you already have the admin user, delete that and add a new admin account with a different name. If you have a few hundred dollars to spare, use sucuri or atleast wordfence with a 2nd degree of security, Last but not least always keep your systems and plugins up to date. By just these 3 you can eliminate 90% of the attacks. Do you know an upto date wordpress has never been breached its the servers that always get breached.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely hacked.  I work with this type of problem every day.

Omer Farooq is correct in that using Nulled themes / plugins WILL lead to backdoors on your site - especially the CryptoPHP backdoor.

Anything that is encrypted should be mistrusted and investigated further.  You may not always be able to decrypt it as hackers sometimes use more than one layer of encryption to obfuscate their code.  This is in an effort to fool 'security plugins' (note the '' as I have yet to find one that actually works) as they tend to scan for code signatures.  They are thus easily fooled.

Solution:

Download a clean copy of Wordpress and extract it to a folder.  Now view that folder side-by-side with the contents of your website's home directory.  You may find one or two files starting with wp_ that should not be there.  View the code - if it is encrypted, remove it.
Also check the time stamps on all files and folders as it will give you an idea of what was changed.

When everything else fails, contact me for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Most Wordpress hacks exploits outdated plugins. You should always update them. Unfortunately, Wordpress is well know for this types of hacking.

Only one time, i had an issue where hosting provider servers were compromised. This is really weird.

If I were in your shoes, i would,

1. Make a database backup
2. Make a file backup (just in case)
3. Delete all files
4. Reinstall latest version of Wordpress
5. Import database (make sure posts were not compromised or if there
   are users that you don't recognize, remove them)
6. Install latest plugins
7. Install theme (if needed)

Also i would setup the compromised website in a virtual machine (locally) and learn how you get compromised (optional)

Comment: Thanks, got a lot of good info here. The only problem is that I have like 80 sites who could be hacked since I found this hack accross multiple servers..  So this is gonna take really lots of time...